# extreme architecture of neuron network

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence

i have quick simple question about neuron network. As we all know, it is better to make the network deeper instead of wider. So what will happen if i set each hidden layer to be just one neuron and expand my network really deep?

This question is raised because i had a lecture about CNN today. The reason why we use CNN is that we want to extract the features of images and decrease the dimensions of the input data. Since we keep making the input for each layer smaller and smaller, why not just use one neuron and make network deeper? Or something bad will happen?

thanks!

Comment: Please check ["Which site?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-do-i-post-in)

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, the single-neuron example doesn't work -- otherwise, that's what we'd use.

The kernels of each layer in a CNN harness spatial relationships and evaluate those juxtapositions with *non-linear* functions, which are the main differentiation of a CNN over a simple linear-combination NN.  Without those non-linear operations, the CNN layers are merely a programming convenience.

If you immediately collapse your input to a single value, you have a *huge* problem in trying to write the cascading non-linearities that comprise the output evaluation.  Yes, it's theoretically *possible* to write a function with, say, 28x28x3 inputs and exactly the output you want -- and to train the multitiude of parameters in that function -- but it's *very* messy to code and nearly impossible to maintain.

For instance, imagine trying to code an entire income tax form in a single function, such that the input was the entire range of applicable monetary amounts, Boolean status info, scalar arguments (e.g. how many children are live at home), ... and have the output be the correct amount of your payment or refund.  There are many Boolean equations to apply, step functions with changing tax rates, various categories of additional tax or relief, etc.

Now, parameterize all of the constant coefficients in that massive calculation.  Get some 10^6 real-life observations, and train your model on *only* that input and labels (tax/refund amount).  You don't get *any* intermediate results to check, *only* that final amount.

It's possible, but not easy to write, debug, or maintain.